# Is praeter formed by adding prefix prae- to stem inter?

Tags: etymology, prefix

The Oxford Latin Dictionary Says

> praeter   prep.,  adv.  and  con}.  [prae-;  for  term.  cf. INTER1]

Does it mean that praeter is formed by adding prefix prae- to stem inter?

How shall I understand the meaning of praeter as derived from those of prae- and inter?

See the relevant entries in the Oxford Latin Dictionary:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

[image]

[image]

Updated:

Which meaning in the dictionary is for the suffix -ter in praeter?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's saying that the *termination* is the same as INTER1. In other words, the *-ter* in these prepositions has the same origin. See also Ancient Greek -τερος.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Which meaning in the dictionary is for the suffix -ter in praeter?See https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQPtF.png (ironically, I can only upload the screenshot but can't see it, because it is hosted at imgur) (2) Can the meaning of praeter be understood from the meanings of prae- and -ter?

Comment: @Tim The screenshot does not give any "meaning" as such of the word "ter," but insofar as it suggests the suffix is "often used to form opposing pairs" of words, I would venture that *praeter* and *propter* can be viewed as such a pair. The Early Latin phrase *praeter propter* ("more or less, roundabout") certainly suggests so.